# How to dynamically create delete buttons which action the row it is in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've created an ASP.NET MVC5 app with signalR for the backend and using javascript for the front end (it's mainly for learning). Functionally, it's very simple it just allows any connected client to see a list of items and each client can add/delete an item. Any changes to the list are updated asynchronously on all clients.

I've got it working so I can add items which will dynamically create a new row in the table and each addition will make the corresponding call on the web server. Each row of the table adds a delete button but I'm not sure how to hook this up to a handler which can then make a signalR call to the server to remove the associated item to the delete button. Can anyone tell me how I can do this please?

My javascript code is here:

```
(function () {
var itemHub = $.connection.itemHub;

var updateItems = function (items) {
    $("#item-list").empty();

    var table = $("<br/><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\"></table>");
    var tableRow = $("<tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Delete</b></td></tr>");
    table.append(tableRow);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        tableRow = $("<tr><td>" + items[i] + "</td><td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" id=\"Delete" + i + "\"></td></tr>");
        table.append(tableRow);
    }
    $("#item-list").append(table);
};

$("#submit").on("click",
    function () {
        var text = $("#textname").val();
        itemHub.server.addItem(text)
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Adding item: " + text);
                $("#textname").val("");
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
    });

itemHub.client.itemListUpdated = updateItems;

$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        console.log("Connected to SignalR hub");
        itemHub.server.getItems()
            .done(function (items) {
                updateItems(items);
            })
            .fail(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
    })
    .fail(function (e) { console.log(e); });
})();
```

The server call to delete the item would be: itemHub.server.deleteItem(text) where "text" is the same string that was added.

Comment: Add an event handler in your loop, and beware the loop closure bug.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If I add an event handler for the delete button, then how can I know from the handler which delete button called it? Ultimately, I need the item name for the associated delete button and make a web server call using it. I'm not sure how this can be done if the event handler is created dynamically.

Comment: You can do that when you create it and use a closure (but not directly in a loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "input[value=Delete]", function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents("tr");
    var item = $row.find("td").first().text();
    itemHub.server.removeItem(item);// or whatever is the function for removing items.
    $row.remove();
});
```

This works because in the callback of a jQuery event listener, `this` refers to the clicked element `event.target`.
So, what this does, is to get the row the clicked element is in, get the text of the first column of that row (the item) and remove the item and the row.

You should probably give all your *delete* buttons a class name so you can use that class name instead of `input[value=Delete]` as a selector.

Comment: So I changed my code to this but still doesn't work. I added this code just below my updateItems:

    $("input[value=Delete]").click(function () {
        var $row = $(this).parents("tr");
        var item = $row.find("td").first().text();
        itemHub.server.deleteItem(item);
        $row.remove();
    });

Comment: @millie I've edited my answer to address that, I forgot that these are dynamically created elements.

Comment: thank you so much, that last one worked perfectly. So if I gave the delete button a class name of "itemdelete", how do I change the selector to work with that?

Comment: @millie: Learn the basics of CSS selectors.

Comment: @millie You will use `.itemdelete` instead of `input[value=Delete]`. Don't forget the dot at the start